# The intel-microcode package causes random errors

Tags: 12.04, intel

I installed the latest intel-microcode package and I'm getting random system error boxes coming up. I assume this is due to the wrong microcode being loaded at boot-up, but I checked the Intel website and my CPU (Core 2 Duo) is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random application crashes and system crashes are not seldom these days in Ubuntu. The only best recommended action we could do is simply report it to either your Intel developer or to Its launchpad page where Ubuntu developers deals with crashes/bugs.

At the edge of the cross window you can find the report Option and you can use it to report them. else you can use apport too.

That will help you to collect information about your application. If you want know more about reporting with apport , https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport

Comment: Thanks. I typically report all crashes to the developers, but I'm sure they're sick of the duplicate reports by now.